# Use of ArrayList in Java to store Name and Age

Tags: java

I want to add both String and Integer type of value in ArrayList.

For example i have array list in which i want to add name of the persons and age of the corresponding person in a single arralist.

How can i accomplish this. How can i get this? Actually i am retrieving data from database and want to save all the employee names and ages in a single array list. Like multidimensional array list.

Comment: Wow that's a lot of answers saying the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a a person class with age and name, then create an ArrayList of that type.

```
class Person {
  private String mName;
  private int mAge;
  public Person(int age, String name) {
     mName = name;
     mAge = age;
  }
  public String getName() {
     return mName;
  }
  etc ........
}

ArrayList<Person> arr = new ArrayList<Person>();
arr.add(new Person(10, "joe"));
```

Comment: This is a good answer--what you'll find is that you actually always needed a Person class--you didn't design your code right.  The desire to store this pair of values in the same collection is a hint that tells you exactly that.  You should add methods to "Person" whenever you have anything that operates on name and/or age and you may even find you have more values that belong here.

Answer (score 6):

You should create a class to represent a person and then add *those* to a list. It's a bad practice to mix the type of objects in a list. You could start with a simple person class:

```
class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Then create a list like this:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

And add people that you read from the database to the list:

```
people.add(new Person(name, age));
```

Comment: ok, Friend. But suppose i have 200 records than 1000 objects will be needed. I think it will degrade my performance. I am actuallt doing this project in android ?

Comment: I was going to vote this up but noticed the public variables.  Ryan's answer is more complete (Although honestly I start out this way a lot--it's just that as Person evolves into a real class with it's own methods and more attributes I always wish I'd just made the variables private in the first place)

Comment: @Durga Dutt No, this is exactly how you code good OO.  Also NEVER make an assumption based on a perceived performance issue--test before you do anything.  In general though you'll probably find this performing better than other solutions due to the fact that it's an OO language and is optimized for OO coding.

Comment: @Durga: It's almost certainly not going to be a performance concern for that many records. @Bill is right, don't optimize until you know you need to. And I highly doubt that you'll need to for this case.

Comment: @Bill: yeah I missed the private fields and getter methods the first time around. I've since updated the answer for completeness. I'd probably even make them final as well, but I imagine setters might be desired and it doesn't matter too much for this example.

Comment: @WhiteFang34 Yeah, I'll revoke my revocation of the vote :)  And you are right, always start with final, it's easy enough to remove if you need to--In fact I wish Java defaulted to private final and overrode with "changable" or something.  (And you shouldn't be able to override private--they should all just be private... period)

Comment: @Bill: I wish the default was private final too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple [`ArrayList`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and add the boxed type of `int`, [`Integer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) along with `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Person Class

```
class Person{
 String name;
 int age;
 //Add the getteres and setters
}
```

Then declare an arrayList as follows.

```
ArrayList<Person> p = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Then for each person create a person object and populate the arrayList as follows.

```
p.add(personObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `ArrayList<Object>`. Both `Integer` and `String` are subclasses of `Object`, and so both can be added to an `ArrayList<Object>`.

That said, it seems unlikely to me that you'd really want to do this. An `ArrayList` is a list. It's generally a bad smell (ie: a sign of a poor design) if you're storing things in a list that aren't the same kind of thing in some sense.

Having a correspondence between elements as you describe suggests that you actually want a list of employee objects, where each employee object has a name and an age.

Another possibility would be to use a `Map` if the names are unique. You can use a `LinkedHashMap` if you care about preserving order.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee{
int age;
String name;
//+acessor method
}

Lit<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the compiler doesn't complain, use Generics to specify that you want to add Objects to your ArrayList; this will let you add both types Integer and String to it:

`ArrayList<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>();`

Then you can add your objects of either type to it.

However, Java is strongly-typed for a reason, so the need to add two types into one ArrayList suggests a design problem to me.